# Problem with deallocation of AVPlayer/AVPlayerItem

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, tvos, avplayeritem

I implemented a code to check if AVPlayer deallocates. Unfortunately it does not. Do I miss something?

```
func testPlayerDealloc() {
    var player: AVPlayer? = AVPlayer()
    weak var weakPlayer = player
    weak var weakPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem?
    let urlString = "http://csm-e.cds1.yospace.com/csm/extlive/yospace02,hlssample.m3u8"
    if let player = player, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        weakPlayerItem = playerItem
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
    }
    player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: nil)
    player = nil
    XCTAssertNil(weakPlayer)
    XCTAssertNil(weakPlayerItem)
}
```

At the end both, the weakPlayer and the weakPlayerItem are not nil.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint a the end of test. And then you can use a Debug memory graph to analyze who exactly retain instances. Here is [a WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/410/) with description of the Debug memory graph.

Comment: I tried it, but nothing came up

Comment: Calling replaceCurrentItem() to define a player item kicks off async loading, that is likely all still going on at the end of the tests. You will need to give the test some time to load, then drop refs and give the threads time to end.

Comment: Did you remember how long it takes? I tried to wait for around 4 seconds. After 4 seconds the objects were not deallocated.